# How can I say that I am doing something currently?

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english

I'm new, so please help me if I'm doing the wrong thing. I read the help section but I'm not sure if this is OK.

I want to know how to say

> I am go to school for study English.
>   I go school for study English.

I don't know how to construct the sentence correctly. Can you teach me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange! You are doing fine. However, just a tip. You may want to consider writing more details, try to be specific and show any research or resources. I'm fairly new myself and found out some people are pretty vicious on here.

> a.) I **am go** to school **for** study English.
>
> b.) I **go school** **for** study English.

I have bold typed your errors.

If you want to tell somone what you do now in general.

> I go to school to study English.

If you are currently **in process**: You are moving your feet and walking **right now** you say:

> I **am going** to school to study English.

This seems to be a common mistake you are making as well: **for**

In this sentence it is possible to say:

> *What do you go to school for?*
>
> I go to school **for a class** in English.

Answer (score 0):

> I am go to school for study English.

"I am going to school to study English."

If you ***really*** want to use the word "for", you would construct the sentence like this:

"I am going to school **for the purpose of** study**ing** English."

Answer (score 0):

I am in school studying English.

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL! We expect our answers to be detailed and explanatory. Can you say a bit more why your suggested sentence works in the OP's context?